# Custom class with an entity and RIA Services/Silverlight

Tags: wcf, silverlight, wcf-ria-services

I have a class with looks like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class TestBatchWithHistoryResult
{
    [Key]
    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string LastRequestedBy { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime? LastRun { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Collection<string> LastConfigurations { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public TestBatch Entity { get; set; }
}
```

When I build the website and Silverlight project and find that the Entity property is not created in the "auto-generated" code on the Silverlight side, but all the other properties are present.

What could be preventing the Entity property from being created?

Thanks

Michael

Answer (score 0):

If the data contract is not referenced by any of your services, it will not be present. Only referenced data contracts are generated. If it is not referenced but it should be (ie if it is a type inherited from one that is returned, and will be returned at some point) use the ServiceKnowTypeAttribute to declare it at the beginning of you service contract.

Comment: Hi Paul. The TestBatch class, returned by the Entity property, is reference by other operations on the service, but when this class is generated in the Silverlight project the Entity property is not coming across. I placed the KnownType attribute for the TestBatch and this class on the service, but it had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

For child entities to be created on the client-side, you need to have a service method exposing that entity type on the server side, e.g:

```
public IQueryable<TestBatch> GetTestBatches(){}
```

And you also need to have the Include attribute on the property:

```
[Include]
public TestBatch Entity {get; set;}
```